# Dropbox linkFromController presenting page "cancel" button color changed in first time

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, dropbox-api

Dropbox linkFromController presenting page **"cancel"** button color changed in first time.Second time application is opened, it is coming in the normal way.In my tableview did select method,called the dropbox session method to linking the application with the dropbox,

```
if (![[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked])
        {
            [[DBSession sharedSession] linkFromController:self];
        }
```

This is in first time and
[image]

this is in second time,
[image]

Please give me a solution for fixing this problem.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with the example app in the latest version of the SDK. Can you? (The latest version is 1.3.10: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/ios thought 1.3.11 should be up soon.) If you can't reproduce it there, are you doing anything to modify colors of things in toolbars in your app?

Comment: @ Greg : Thank you for your valuable comments. I can reproduce the problem in first time opening of the application.Then quit the app and launch again,there is no problem.In my app,UInavigationbar using a background color.But the problem is coming in first time only.Is there any solution for this?

Comment: This actually looks similar to this thread from the Dropbox API forum: https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=113195 It sounds like for now you can set your background color for each class instead of globally, and we're looking into how we can fix this on our side.

Comment: Ok Greg.Now,i had set the uibarbutton color(white color changed to another color) in my class and that  affected the dropbox screen also.It is worked now.I think, this is not a proper way. Please fix the issue in your side and will make useful in future.